# На iphone появляется лишний border

Tags: css

Проверял отображение на мобильных и заметил что появляется лишний border в формах. Я прикрепил пример для input прописан только нижний border, но на мобильных оно подставляет ещё на скрине видно. Подскажите как исправить прикреплю ещё код css

```css
input
  background-color: transparent
  border: none
  outline: none
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
  padding-left: 30px
  padding-bottom: 10px
  padding-right: 30px
  margin-bottom: 25px
  color: #fff
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder
   color: #fff
  &::-moz-placeholder   
   color: #fff       
  &:-moz-placeholder 
   color: #fff        
  &:-ms-input-placeholder 
   color: #fff
  &:focus, &:hover
   border-bottom: 1px solid $accent
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте вместо border:none прописать border:1px solid transparent;

Comment: да, сработало что то я сразу не подумал что так можно попробовать, много стилей переписал, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, попробуйте вместо `border:none;` прописать `border:1px solid transparent;`